# __init__.py can't find local modules

Tags: python, package, init, python-module

Borrowing a simplified example at http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/

I have an analogous file structure as follows, where Mammals.py and Birds.py define classes with the same names:

```
Project/
  Animals/
    __init__.py
    Mammals.py
    Birds.py
```

When running an ipython interpreter within the `Project/` directory and with `__init__.py` being empty, the following works:

```
from Animals.Mammals import Mammals
x = Mammals()
x.printMammals()
```

I'd like to be able to write `from Animals import Mammals` instead of `from Animals.Mammals import Mammals`. And I believe the way to do that is to make the `__init__.py` file contents the following:

```
from Mammals import Mammals
from Birds import Birds
```

However, when this is done, from within a similarly `Project/` sourced ipython interpreter, the following input produces an error:

```
In [1]: from Animals import Mammals
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6d651848af9b> in <module>()
----> 1 from Animals import Mammals

/Users/username/Project/Animals/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from Mammals import Mammals
      2 from Birds import Birds

ImportError: No module named 'Mammals'
```

I feel that there is simple mistake that I am making, but can't find. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `from Animals.Mammals` will work if you are on the same directory level as the `Animals` module. And I don't think you need any imports inside of `__init__.py` unless you want to import additional modules when you do `import Animals`

Comment: Do you really mean you run the interpreter from inside `Project/` or do you mean you run it from inside `Animals`? If you have the file structure you describe and run the interpreter from `Project/` it should work with an empty `__init__.py` as well.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Put the following codes in the `__init__.py` inside the `Animals` directory.

Python 3.x :

```
from .Mammals import Mammals
from .Birds import Birds
```

On 2.x:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .Mammals import Mammals
from .Birds import Birds
```

**Explanation:**

It can't find the module because it doesn't know what directory to search to find the files `Mammals` and `Birds`.  You're assuming that the subfolder `Animals` gets added to the python search path, but if you check `sys.path` (executed from `Projects/Animals/__init__.py`) you'll see that only the path to `Project` is on the path.  I'm not sure why the directory containing `Project/Animals/__init__.py` is not searched, since that's the code being executed, but the error indicates this is the cause.

Putting a `.` before the module name tells Python that the module you're loading is inside the current module's directory.

(Thanks to @SeanM's comment for explaining.)

Comment: Thanks! This works. Do you know if this is a standard way to structure `__init__.py` files?

Comment: It is often done - mostly for commonly used classes, functions so they can be easily imported without typing long import paths. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Can someone supply a reference on why there is a '.' before the imported file name? Looking at a package I constructed a few years ago, it appears that @DarrenMcAffee code should have worked as posed.

Comment: It looks like this issue is a path directory problem. If the folder Project/Animals is properly added to the sys.path and/or PYTHONPATH then you don't need the .Mammals rather than Mammals. Clarification on this issue would be welcome.

Comment: This is a non informative answer, as it 1. does not explain why the user code has such a problem 2. it does not explain why the solution fixes the problem. The only way to make use of this answer is by copy-pasting from it, and it does not help in understanding what happens. Please elaborate on the source of the problem, I'd love to upvote such answer

Comment: Added an attempt at explanation.

Comment: Reading through this article helped me to clearly understand the root cause of the issue: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Comment: How would one go about importing one of these modules into another, e.g. for typing purposes, without causing an import loop error? e.g. you add a Penguin.py that extends Birds and import both to __init__ in this manner

Comment: If I add `Mice.py` and have it `import Mammals` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` and if I try to use `from .Mammals import Mammals` I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Mammals' from 'Animals.Mammals'` What's a work around for this?